# when compiling this c program "non portable pointer conversion" warning is occuring so what is the reason behind this warning?

Tags: c, data-structures

Defination :

Create a “Queue” user-defined structure with the following data members:

1. A Data
2. A link to the next node
   Perform the following operations on Simple queue using user-defined functions:
3. Insert an element
4. Remove an element
5. Display
6. Isfull
7. Isempty
   Create a file which stores all values of list.

Code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct queue{
    int data;
    struct queue *next;
};
typedef struct queue node;
node *start=NULL,*rear=NULL;
int choice,i;
void insert();
void rem();
void display();
void isfull();
void isempty();
int main()
{
    do
    {
        printf("\n\t 1.Insert\n\t 2.Remove\n\t 3.Display\n\t 4.isfull\n\t 5.isempty\n\t 6. Exit\n");
        printf("\n Enter the Choice:");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                insert();
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                rem();
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                display();
                break;
            }
            case 4:
            {
                isfull();
                break;
            }
            case 5:
            {
                isempty();
                break;
            }
            case 6:
            {
                printf("\n\t EXIT POINT ");
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                printf ("\n\t Please Enter a Valid Choice(1/2/3/4/5/6)");
            }
        }
    }
    while(choice!=6);
    return 0;
}
void insert()
{
    node *temp;
    temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(temp==NULL){
       printf("\n\tQueue is Full\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Enter a value to be inserted:");
        scanf("%d",&i);
        temp->data = i;
        temp->next=NULL;
        if(start==NULL){
            start = temp;
            rear = temp;
        }
        else{
            rear->next = temp;
            rear = temp;
        }
    }
}
void rem()
{
    node *temp;
    if(start==NULL)
    {
    printf("\n\t Queue is Empty \n");
    }
    else
    {
    temp = start;
    start = start->next;
    printf("\n\t The deleted element is %d",temp->data);
    free(temp);
    }
}
void display()
{
    node *temp;
    if(start!=NULL)
    {
    temp = start;
    while(temp->next!=NULL){
        printf(" %d -> ",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf(" %d",temp->data);
    }
    else
    {
    printf("\n The Queue is empty");
    }
}
void isfull()
{
    node *temp;
    if (rear == temp - 1)
    printf("Queue Overflow \n");
    else
    printf("Queue is not a Overflow\n");
}
void isempty()
{
    node *temp;
    if (start == - 1)
    printf("Queue is empty \n");
    else
    printf("Queue is not a empty\n");
}
```

Looking out for some genuine solution please anyone who can answer this one.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Genuine solution to *what* ? [The warnings/errors you should be seeing?](https://godbolt.org/z/6fzqeEEjf) ? They seem pretty self-explanatory. `start` is a pointer-to-int. You're comparing it to `int`. they're not synonymous types. If you aren't familiar with the difference between a 'pointer-to-type' and just 'type` you need to review your learning materials. The rest of those warnings/errors are critical too, btw.

Comment: `if (start == - 1)` is invalid.  What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are comparing an integer value to pointer value you can fix it by replacing -1 to NULL in isempty function it will work perfectly without any warning. There is no need of -1 you need it when you make start and rear variables inside the structure and there data type should be int.

hope it solves your problem